# Jquery show next and hide prev issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

Trying to hide the previous element and then show the next element however the code is not working. It needs to be that every .quiz-group show the next but also hide the previous when the more button is clicked.

Code is:

```
x=1;

$('.quiz-group:lt('+x+')').show();

 $('.more').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    x= (x+3 <= quiz_groups) ? x+3 : quiz_groups;
    $('.quiz-group:lt('+x+')').slideDown();
    $('.quiz-group').not(':lt('+x+')').slideUp();
    $('.back').show();
});
```

HTML is:

```
<div class="quiz-group">
 <ul class="question-single">
  <li>
   <p>text?</p>
     <ul class="answer">
      <li>Answer 1</li>
      <li>Answer 2</li>
      <li>Answer 3</li>
    </ul> 
  </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

The code iterates through each third question and adds the quiz-group div wrapper.

Currently it appends the quiz group to the existing (not hiding the previous one).

Thanks

Comment: Post a fiddle with your code. It's not good to assume one's problems!

Comment: Code is about 300 lines long with a mixture of PHP/HTML/CSS/JS and WordPress - Issue is only this part.

Comment: at least post the `html` part

Comment: Just post all the relevant code that can reproduce the problem.

Comment: Any chance of some help on this?